# Does not showing indiviual state in react js?

Tags: reactjs

showing the same state,but i want display indiviual state.when i click the hospital its not showing hospital component but both hospital,fireservice showing same state.click function worked but not showing the indiviual component only showing same component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './importantplaces.css';
import Showhospital from './Hospitallist/Showhospital';
import Showfireservice from './Fireservice/Showfireservice';

export default class Importantplaces extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            showHospital: false,
            showFire: false
        }
    }
    onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ showHospital: !this.state.showHospital })
        this.setState({ showFire: !this.state.showFire })

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Importantplaces">
            <div className="placelist">
            <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} className="place-content p-btn mb-70">Hospital</a>
                        <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} className="place-content p-btn mb-70">Fire Service</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">

                        <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} className="place-content p-btn mb-70">Police Station</a>
                        <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} className="place-content p-btn mb-70">Post Office</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            {this.state.showHospital && <Showhospital />}
            {this.state.showFire && <Showfireservice />}
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are changing both your state on the click event. So they both always go from false to true and back to false.

You have different way to solve this : adding an argument to your onclick function to define which state should go to true, or making different onClick function for each component you want to show. Second solution would go as such :

```
<a onClick={this.onHospitalClick.bind(this)} className="place-content p-btn mb-70">Hospital</a>
<a onClick={this.onFireServiceClick.bind(this)} className="place-content p-btn mb-70">Fire Service</a>
```

and having these two functions instead :

```
onHospitalClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ showHospital: true, showFire : false })
}

onFireServiceClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ showHospital: false, showFire : true })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code you can use one function to onclick

```js
class B extends React.Component {
   render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <h1>BBBB</h1>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

class C extends React.Component {
   render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <h1>CCCC</h1>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

class A extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showB: false,
      showC: false,
    }
    
    this.handleMultiSelect = this.handleMultiSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleMultiSelect(val) {
    console.log('aaaa', val);
    if(val === 'b'){
      this.setState({
        showB: !this.state.showB
      });
    } else if(val === 'c'){
      this.setState({
        showC: !this.state.showC
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <a onClick={() => {this.handleMultiSelect('b')}}>B</a>
      <br />
      <a onClick={() => {this.handleMultiSelect('c')}}>C</a>
      {this.state.showB && <B/>}
      {this.state.showC && <C/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < A / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```